# What does 'Ѐ' in "new byte['Ѐ']" mean?

Tags: java, byte

I'm reading some source code in java to learn from it. There's a line I don't understand:

```
byte[] c = new byte['Ѐ'];
```

What does the 'Ѐ' character mean in this case? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It means the character `Ѐ`, but because it is being used as an array size, it is interpreted as an integer (its [unicode value](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0400) 1024).

Comment: Characters are stored in one byte and the primitve type `char` can also be interpreted as an `int`. The 'value' of `È` is 200 and therefore the array c has a size of 200.

Comment: @L.Spillner `(int)'Ѐ'` is 1024.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a *weird* character :)

Comment: @Ivar Oh it's a cyrillic E with grave... I used the latin one. Tanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That looks like something that a decompiler might produce. Numbers and characters look the same in Java byte code and sometimes the decompiler has to "guess" which one it is and it might have guessed wrong here.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It would be a weird choice for a decompiler to decide that a constant used as an array size would be a `char`.

Comment: I feel a developer found that it was much cooler to use a char for the size ... but in the end it is just adding complexity for every other reader.

Comment: @khelwood: true, but I've seen compilers make worse choices than that and it would be equally weird for a *human* to make that choice. Technically it's allowed, so whoever produced it isn't *wrong*, necessarily.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I guess I'm less surprised by weird choices from humans.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I did use JD GUI to decompile it. Maybe that's why.

Comment: @DatBoringName: that will most certainly be the reason. The original code probably just had a simple `new byte[1024]` or even `new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The size in array creation expressions are usually of type `int`; but you can use anything of type `byte`, `char` or `short` instead, as they can be widened to an `int`. This is described in [JLS Sec 15.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1).

In this case, `'Ѐ'` is simply being used instead of `1024`, so it's exactly the same as `new byte[1024]`.

It's impossible to say exactly why it is written like this without seeing more of your code; but that's what it does.